# Count of related records but limit results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have tables of CUSTOMERS and ORDERS, related by customer_id.
I just want to get the count of number of orders that have been placed by each customer.
I was successful with this example [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e7223/10/0)
.

However, the recordset is large and I just want to get the total number of records for each customer limited to those that have had that number change recently. One possible solution, list all customers that have placed an order in the last 30 days, and list their total number of orders ever placed.

I tried one approach with this [other SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e7223/9/0). I am trying to SELECT TOP 3 customers and their total number of orders, sorted by their order date.
This doesn't work, and only shows the number of orders placed by each customer within that truncated time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're a bit confused with your `SELECT TOP (3)` and `ORDER BY`.

Go with your initial query with an additional `WHERE` clause;

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(order_id) AS num_orders 
FROM Customers 
LEFT JOIN Orders ON (customer_id = cust_id) 
WHERE order_date > DATE() - 30 // or desired equivalent
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Edit

As per your latest comment...

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(order_id) AS num_orders 
FROM Customers 
LEFT JOIN Orders ON (customer_id = cust_id) 
WHERE customer_id IN(SELECT TOP (3) [cust_id] FROM Orders ORDER BY [order_date] DESC)
GROUP BY customer_id
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e7223/50)

This will select the ids of the most recent three orders and return the total number of orders for each associated customer.

Comment: Per [new sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e7223/27/0) this doesn't give the expected result

Comment: Sorry, forgot to enclose the date string in single quotes. Still doesn't work as expected. Example [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e7223/41) only counts orders placed since given date, not total orders

Answer (score 1):

*"SELECT TOP 3 customers and their total number of orders, sorted by their order date"*

In order to get `TOP 3` customers based on their numbers of orders, you first need to `"ORDER BY num_orders DESC"`.  Include `customer_id` in the `ORDER BY` as a tie-breaker in case multiple customers have the 3rd-highest order count.

```
SELECT TOP 3
    sub.customer_id,
    sub.num_orders,
    sub.last_order_date
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            c.customer_id,
            Count(o.order_id) AS num_orders,
            Max(o.order_date) AS last_order_date
        FROM
            Customers AS c
            LEFT JOIN Orders AS o
            ON c.customer_id = o.cust_id
        WHERE o.order_date > Date() - 30
        GROUP BY c.customer_id
    ) AS sub
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1;
```

That should give you the top 3 customers.  If you then want to see them sorted by `last_order_date`, use that sql in a subquery and apply `ORDER BY last_order_date` to the subquery result set.

Per your comment, top 3 customers means the 3 who placed orders most recently.  That is actually an easier query because you need only one `ORDER BY` for both the `TOP 3` and the final sort order.  Change the `ORDER BY` in the query above to this ...

```
ORDER BY 3 DESC, 1;
```

If `num_orders` should be the number of orders the customers placed since the start of time --- ie not just those orders placed in the last 30 days --- save this query as *Query1*:

```
SELECT TOP 3
    sub.cust_id,
    sub.last_order_date
FROM
    (
        FROM Orders AS o
        WHERE o.order_date > Date() - 30
        GROUP BY o.cust_id
    ) AS sub
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1;
```

Then save this query as *Query2*:

```
SELECT
    o.cust_id,
    Count(o.order_id) AS num_orders
FROM Orders AS o
GROUP BY o.cust_id;
```

Finally create a third query which inner joins *Query1* with *Query2*: *Query1* gives you the most recent 3 customers and the date of their last order; *Query2* gives you the total number of all orders placed by each customer; `INNER JOIN` filters the rows returned from *Query2* to only those customers present in *Query1*.

Comment: Sorry for confusion - I am not looking for top three customers based on number of orders they've placed. I am looking for top three customers based on recentness of order, and the total number of orders those customers have placed.

Comment: See [example usage](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e7223/44) of modified query. It only shows '1' order for customer_id = 1, when I am after their total number of orders.

Comment: Does that mean you want to select from those customers who have placed orders within the last 30 days, but retrieve the number of their orders for all time --- not just those orders they placed within the last 30 days?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Limiting on a specific timeframe isn't necessary, but I want to get total number of orders per customer, ONLY for customers where that number has recently changed.